# How to find by two conditions and push into array in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have schema like this:

```
this.schema = new Schema({
    userId: String,
    userEmail: String,
    preference: {
        language: String,
        enableEmailNotifications: Boolean
        Schedule: {
            EmailFrequency: String,
            weekDay: String
        }
    },

    environments: [
        {
            envId: String,
            userPreference: {
                language: String,
                emailNotifications: Boolean,
                Schedule: {
                    weekDay: String
                    timeOfTheDay: String
                }
            },
        }
    ]
});
```

I need to find the user by `userEmail` and then find `environment` object by `envId` from array of objects and push new `userPreference` obj into `environments` array

Tried this:

```
var obj = {
    $push: { preference }
}

const result = await preferencesModel.findOne({ userEmail, "environments.envId": { "$in": envId } }, obj, { upsert: true, new: true });
```

but getting error: `MongoError: Unsupported projection option: $push: { preference: ...`

Update:

```
const result = await preferencesModel.findOneAndUpdate({ userEmail, "environments.envId": envId }, obj, { upsert: true, new: true });
```

Object I am trying to insert into array:

```
{
    "envId": "u1",
    "userEmail": "test@gmail.com",
    "userPreference": {
        "language": "en",
        "timeZone": "gmt",
        "enableEmailNotifications": true,
        "summaryNotifications": true,
        "summaryNotificationSchedule": {
            "summaryEmailFrequency": "Weekly",
            "weekDay": "Monday",
            "timeOfTheDay": "32400"
        }
    }
}
```

All of the properties are not being inserted as you can see below:

```
"environments": [
    {
      "userPreference": {
        "summaryNotificationSchedule": {
          "timeOfTheDay": "32400",
          "weekDay": "Monday"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "timeZone": "gmt",
        "summaryNotifications": true
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f5fcb23e8706e3f9c7ccdbc"
      },
      "envId": "u1"
    },
    {
      "userPreference": {
        "summaryNotificationSchedule": {
          "timeOfTheDay": "32400"
        }
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f5fcb72e8706e3f9c7ccdbf"
      }
    }
  ]
```

`"language": "en", "timeZone": "gmt"` are missing

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs to updated this way :-

```
var email = 'testemail@123.com';
var id = 'abc123';
var newPreference = {
  //contains data according to your schema defination
}
console.log('Preference to be added :-\n', newPreference); 
//check your preference which is getting pushed, it might not contain the complete data you seek.

var obj = {
    $push: { environments: newPreference } 
}

const result = await preferencesModel.findOneAndUpdate({
   userEmail: email, 
   "environments.envId": id, 
}, 
obj,
{ 
   upsert: true, 
   new: true 
});
```

You can match multiple conditions in the first argument of findOneAndUpdate as the first argument can contain any number of conditions you want to impose on the document you are trying to get.

Also to find a static value inside an array you need not to use $in operator. You can simply use "." (dot) on the array property like i have shown you in above example.

You can more out here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: I tried your example but the array count has not changed that means object is not getting pushed into array

Comment: I have updated the solution!  please check the edit quote too.

Comment: Actually all object properties are not being inserted. Only partial insertion happens

Comment: Updated the question. Please check once

Comment: Consider checking your newPreference you are pushing once, the query seems to be correct!

Comment: I checked the logs. I am sending all the properties but some how mongo is not saving nested object properties into array

Comment: Please share the object you are pushing here for once!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221479/discussion-between-abhijeet-raj-and-kittu).

Comment: Posted into question